# Why isn't .tif exported in AdobeRGB colorprofile, but the .jpg is

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, nuke

For the project I'm working with Python 3.8 in PyCharm and the following libraries:
Pillow, os and configparser.

I've been trying the convert images to the colorprofile AdobeRGB and I thought I finally made it work, but it seems to work only for .jpg files and not the .tif files. While I'm doing the same for both of them. Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?

The code that I'm using:

```
backplate = config['BACKPLATE']['backplate']
backplate1 = Image.open(backplate)
icc_adobe = backplate1.info.get('icc_profile')

for versie, render, nameMin in zip(fileVersion, renders, fileNameMin):
    os.chdir(path + '\\' + versie)
    path = os.getcwd()

    imageAdobe_tif = Image.open(render)
    imageAdobe_tif = imageAdobe_tif.save(path + '\\' + nameMin + '.tif', icc_profile=icc_adobe)
    imageAdobe_jpg = Image.open(render)
    imageAdobe_jpg = imageAdobe_jpg.save(path + '\\' + nameMin + '.jpg', icc_profile=icc_adobe)

    path = os.path.dirname(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

## sRGB vs Adobe RGB in NUKE

> `sRGB` gives better, more consistent, results and the same, or brighter, colours. Using `Adobe RGB` is one of the leading causes of colours not matching between monitor and print (however, you won't print, I guess). `sRGB` is the world's default color space. Use it and everything looks great everywhere, all the time.

Here's a code:

```
import nuke

selected_nodes = nuke.selectedNodes()

for node in selected_nodes:
    if node.Class() == "Read":
        node.knob("colorspace").setValue("sRGB")

node.knob("colorspace").value()
```